# Create a chain of N processes where parent creates one child

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork

I have to create four process, Every son has to create one son and just wait for it to finish.

`PROCESS 0 --> PROCESS 1 --> PROCESS 2 --> PROCESS 3 --> PROCESS 4`

How to do it ? I've tried the following so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 
#define NUM_PROC 5


int main (void)
{
    int pid;
    int i;
    int status;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_PROC; i++)
    {
        if ((pid=fork()) <0 )
        {
            printf("Error in forking\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid ==0) {
            printf("Sono: %d, mio padre e: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());     
            pid = fork();
        }
        else {
            printf("Sono: %d, mio padre e: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());   
            wait( &status);
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: So you want people to do your job ? and what is the idea of having multiple processes when the order of execution is as of a single execution. Only adding an overhead of creating process...

Comment: Nono I don't want people to do my job, I've to do it for exercise and I just can't find a possible idea, I'm trying a lot, but I can't manage doing nothing similar

Comment: Could you elaborate on what part you need help with? (Do you understand how to create a process? Do you understand how to wait for a process? Do you understand how to count to four? Do you understand how to combine those three abilities?)

Comment: Yes I do, I'll put what I've done

Comment: Creating a process is very straightforward using `fork()` system call. Look at what `fork()` does and it's return value to `parent\son` process.

Comment: @ruakh  just added the code.

Comment: Wait let me understand, you want main process to create 5 child processes where each one created another child process ? or what ?

Comment: No, is something like, a father creates a son that createas a son ecc ecc, until i've got, totally, ocunting the first father, 5 processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main program is creating a new child process in the loop, which then runs the same loop as the parent and creates more child processes.

Using a `for` loop and generalizing for `N` processes:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
{
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) { // handle error }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        // son process (NO FORK INSIDE THIS ELSE IF!)
    }
    else { // parent process
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It would be a way to do it in a for loop in order to have something more "portable"? Thank you very much in every case